# Go: Templates Embedded in Binary Return Blank Page

Tags: go, templates, embed

Trying to move my golang html templates from files to using `embed`

Works fine:

```
func loadTemplates() multitemplate.Render {
    r := multitemplate.New()

    layouts, err := filepath.Glob("templates/layouts/*.tmpl")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    includes, err := filepath.Glob("templates/includes/*.tmpl")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    // Generate our templates map from our layouts/ and includes/ directories
    for _, layout := range layouts {
        files := append(includes, layout)
        r.Add(filepath.Base(layout), template.Must(template.ParseFiles(files...)))
        log.Println(filepath.Base(layout) + ": " + files[0])
    }

    return r
}
```

Very similar code returns blank page, no errors:

```
//go:embed templates/*
var f embed.FS


func loadTemplates() multitemplate.Render {
    r := multitemplate.New()

    // Generate our templates map from our layouts/ and includes/ directories

    layouts, err := embed.FS.ReadDir(f, "templates/layouts")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    for _, layout := range layouts {
        embeddedTemplate, err := template.ParseFS(f, "templates/layouts/"+layout.Name(), "templates/includes/base.tmpl")
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
        r.Add(layout.Name(), embeddedTemplate)
        log.Println(layout.Name() + " loaded")
    }

    return r
}
```

I confirmed in the debugger that all templates contain no errors and their respective content. Other embedded files such as static assets work fine and get served ok. Even other templates loaded from a database work fine. Just those from `embed` end up blank.

Any hints what's happening here?
Thanks!

**Edit: Full example:**

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "embed"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "path/filepath"

    "github.com/gin-contrib/multitemplate"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

//go:embed templates/*
var f embed.FS

func main() {

    router := gin.Default()
    router.HTMLRender = loadTemplates()

    router.GET("/embed", HomeHandlerEmbed(router))
    router.GET("/file", HomeHandlerFile(router))

    router.Run(":8080")

}

func loadTemplates() multitemplate.Render {
    r := multitemplate.New()

    //load same template from embed FS
    embeddedTemplate, err := template.ParseFS(f, "templates/layouts/home.tmpl", "templates/includes/base.tmpl")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    r.Add("homeEmbed.tmpl", embeddedTemplate)
    log.Println("homeEmbed.tmpl" + " loaded from embed FS")

    // load same template from real file system
    layoutsFile, err := filepath.Glob("templates/layouts/*.tmpl")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    includes, err := filepath.Glob("templates/includes/*.tmpl")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    for _, layout := range layoutsFile {
        files := append(includes, layout)
        r.Add(filepath.Base(layout), template.Must(template.ParseFiles(files...)))
        log.Println(filepath.Base(layout) + ": " + files[0])
    }

    return r

}

func HomeHandlerEmbed(r *gin.Engine) gin.HandlerFunc {

    return gin.HandlerFunc(func(c *gin.Context) {

        c.HTML(200, "homeEmbed.tmpl", nil)

    })
}

func HomeHandlerFile(r *gin.Engine) gin.HandlerFunc {

    return gin.HandlerFunc(func(c *gin.Context) {

        c.HTML(200, "home.tmpl", nil)

    })
}
```

templates/includes/base.tmpl

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
{{template "head" .}}
</head>
<body>

    {{template "body" .}}
  
</body>
</html>
```

templates/layouts/home.tmpl

```
{{define "head"}}<title>Test</title>{{end}}
{{define "body"}}

Body

{{end}}
```

/file works fine, /embed comes up blank

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe it does not need the `templates/` prefix when inside the binary?

Comment: I’ll try, but they seem to get initialized correctly and they have their content as expected when inspected in the debugger. They’re still named by their basename: layout.Name() only returns "home.tmpl" without the path as before.

Comment: What is the error returned from executing the template?

Comment: There’s no error at all. The returned page simply is blank.

Comment: Please add sample contents of `templates/` dir and sample `gin` app. I tried your code with some simplistic setup and it worked fine: https://github.com/pakuula/StackOverflow/tree/main/go/73438924

Comment: @PakUula I added a sample main.go and templates above. Thanks for looking at it!

Comment: Looks like you don't have `homeEmbed.tmpl` file in the file system.

Comment: no, thats just a string to distinguish it in the example. the name you call the template does not have to be a filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function `loadTemplates()` just fix this line:

```golang
embeddedTemplate, err := template.ParseFS(f, "templates/includes/base.tmpl", "templates/layouts/home.tmpl")
```

In your example patterns will be presented in this sequence:

- first: `"templates/layouts/home.tmpl"`
- second: `"templates/includes/base.tmpl"`

But if I understood correctly, the sequence of patterns is important for the function `template.ParseFS`, because `base.tmpl` will be included in all you templates.

The function `template.ParseFS` reads the templates in the process and tries to generate them.